# How to verify datatype before entering into the table

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqldatatypes

I have four columns in a table

```
Id Int
Name varchar(2)
Address varchar (4)
Active bit
```

and the source table with the same columns but have the varchar data type.

```
Id varchar(100)
Name varchar(100)
Address varchar (100)
Active varchar(100)
```

I have to transfer data from source table to destination table, but while transfering I need to check if the row I have has the correct data type for the destination. If not I need to transfer that complete row to some error table. ex.:

```
ID Name Address Active
1  A     A       1
C  B     B       0
3  AAA   C       1 
4  D     D       0
5  K     K       102
```

if above represnt the source table and only rows 1 and 4 are eligible to tranfer to the destination table other rows will be moved to error table (may be with valid description, if possible)

Comment: I would *definitely* recommend that you look into using SSIS for this task, rather than trying to do it in T-SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this

```
insert into destination
select * from source 
where (isnumeric(ID)=1 
        and 
        (ID not like '%[^0-9]%')
        and 
        RIGHT('00000000000'+ID,10) <= '2147483647'
      ) 
      and
      len(name)<=2
      and
      len(Address)<=4
      and
      active in ('0','1')
```

So to insert into ERRORS table use NOT in WHERE

```
insert into ERRORS
select * from source 
where 
   NOT
     (
      (isnumeric(ID)=1 
        and 
        (ID not like '%[^0-9]%')
        and 
        RIGHT('00000000000'+ID,10) <= '2147483647'
      ) 
      and
      len(name)<=2
      and
      len(Address)<=4
      and
      active in ('0','1')
    )
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ceaa8/1)

Comment: `ISNUMERIC('£')` is equal to `1`, but not convertible to an `int`. I think you want `ID not like '%[^0-9]%'`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Query is fixed with your suggestion.

Comment: Now I got an idea how to implement this .. +1 I am implementing your logic  :)